# Resurrecting XNA 3.0 projects

Tags: xna, compatibility

I have some old XNA 3.0 projects that used stuff that has totally been changed in XNA 4.0.

Really I just want to revisit some of my old code, dust it off and refactor it.

Can XNA 3.0 and XNA 4.0 be installed *together* in Visual Studio 2010, or will there be problems?

Should I just install C# Express Edition 2008 with XNA 3.0, and work with my old projects that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the XNA GameStudio frameworks can be installed side-by-side on the same Windows system, [I don't think XNA GameStudio 3.x will work](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/32111.aspx) [with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355497/is-there-any-way-to-use-xna-3-1-with-visual-c-sharp-express-2010).

The good news (sort of) is, that you can install Visual Studio 2008 side-by-side with Visual Studio 2010.  As a matter of fact, I have XNA 3.1, 4.0, and Visual Studio 2005, 2008, and 2010 all installed on my box right now.

Comment: I found Visual Studio 2008 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6506) -- they redirected all the other links!

Comment: Also [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3092) is the ISO if you're interested.